# Garbage characters are printed forcefully

Tags: c, string, character

This is a program that's supposed to read inputs, a number 'n' and a character, and then duplicate this character n times. It works perfectly fine, but when I enter a large number, 8+ for example, it duplicates perfectly but then adds garbage values to the end. I can't get why it does that since I used malloc and I have exactly n blocks saved for me in the memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char* create_string (char ch, int n);
void main ()
{
    int n;
    char ch;
    printf("Enter number for duplicates: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter a letter: ");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
    printf("The letter '%c' duplicated %d times is: ",ch,n);
    char* ptr=create_string(ch,n);
    printf("%s",ptr);
}
char* create_string (char ch, int n)
{
    char* dup=(char*)malloc(n*sizeof(char));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        dup[i]=ch;
    }
    return dup;
}
```

Test run:
[image: Test run.]

Comment: Your `create_string` function does not create a string.

Comment: I cannot see the "Test run" pic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in C are as simple as null-terminated character sequences. That means whenever you create a string by hand, you must always append a `'\0'` at the end so other functions like `printf` know where it ends:

```
char* create_string (char ch, int n)
{
    char* dup = malloc((n+1) * sizeof(char));
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        dup[i]=ch;
    }

    // This is important
    dup[n] = '\0';

    return dup;
}
```

Another subtle thing to notice is that because you need to store that terminating null character, you also need to reserve the space for it. So the `malloc` line is changed into:

```
malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char))
//     ^^^^^ it's no longer 'n'
```

On a side note, you [don't need to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/5958455) cast the returned pointer of `malloc`.

Comment: @KeineLust Looks like I missed that point. Thanks

Comment: Multiplying by `sizeof (char)` is pointless. It's 1 by definition.

Comment: @melpomene Keeping that is harmless and may sometimes be beneficial in terms of readability for beginners.

Comment: Personally, for beginners, I think it is good to show you are setting the adequate size based on (1) the number of elements needed; and (2) the type-size of the object or variable. From that standpoint it probably does more good than harm.

Comment: Remember, we can always use sizeof( *dup ); . There a missing free() call also.

Comment: Yes, where do I add the free() call?

Comment: @YoussefHusseinY When you don't need it anymore. In your case, probably after the `printf` call.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in C are `char` arrays where the character `\0` denotes the end of the string. Since you aren't explicitly adding it, `printf` just prints values from memory until it happens to run in to a terminating character (i.e., this is undefined-behavior). Instead, you should explicitly add this character to your result string:

```
char* create_string (char ch, int n)
{
    char* dup = (char*) malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(char));
    /* Added 1 for the '\0' char ---^ */

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        dup[i]=ch;
    }

    /* Set the terminating char */
    dup[n] = '\0';

    return dup;
}
```